# SQL Server script to read many csv files at certain intervals and insert records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have some csv files. I want to write SQL Server script to read the file at certain period and insert in SQL Server db, if record is not found and ignore it if file has already been read previously by scheduler. Each csv will contain one record only.

Like:

```
1.csv => John,2000,2012/12/12
2.csv => Tom,3000,2012/12/11
```

It will be great if someone can provide examples of script.

Thanks!

Comment: Though, SSIS is meant for these kind of processes and Kenneth has already given you the steps.. but still if you want to script you can create a file log table where you can capture the file details after processing. You can keep the script running through out a day with some loop like *WHILE(1==1)* and use **WAITFOR DELAY HH:MM:SS**  to make it behave like a schedular (To let you know, the solution which I have written is not a perfect one, and I will not recommend you to do it also, use SSIS). 

In case of sql script use **BULK INSERT** with required row and column delimeter.

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I would create an SSIS package that uses the multi file input.  This input let's you pull data from every file in a directory.

Here are the basic steps for your SSIS package.

1. Check if there are any files in the "working" directory.  If not end the package.
2. Move every file from your "working" directory to a "staging" directory.
    You will do this so that if additional files appear in your "working" directory while you are in the midst of the package you won't lose them.
3. Read all of the files in the "staging" directory.  Use a data flow with the multi file input.
4. Once the reading has been completed then move all of the files to a
   "backup" directory. 
    This of course assumes you want to keep them for some reason.  You could just as easily delete them from the "staging" directory.

Once you have your package completed then schedule it using SQL Server agent to run the package at whatever interval you are interested in.